# How to manage CRSV token manually in Symfony?

Tags: security, symfony

I'm trying to use the CRSF token management without a FormType. So in a twig template i just use that to generate a token:

```
{{ csrf_token( inception_inscription ) }}
```

In the controller i'm trying this :

```
    $tokenManager = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
    $token = $request->get('token');
    inception = $this->container->getParameter('crsf_inscription_inception');
    if (!$tokenManager->isTokenValid($tokenManager->getToken($inception, $token))) {
        throw new HttpException(400, 'Invalid token');
    }
```

But in fact the method isTokenValid always return true. I can force the $token vaiable to what i want, it's never false, so the validation is useless.

When i do debug step by step, i walk throught a Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf::getToken() and that method is testing that :  ($this->storage->hasToken($tokenId)) whic always return false and force the process to generate a new Token.

I don't really undertand how it works. 
Here is ore information about my code :
Symfony 2.6.x

```
framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:
        csrf_protection:
            enabled:      true
            field_name:   token_my
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:  true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id:  ~
        name:       'my'
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        inception_inscription:  %crsf_inscription_inception%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, $tokenManager->getToken($tokenId) always generates a new, valid token. You would probably check the provided token instead, e.g.:

```
$tokenManager = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
$tokenId = $this->container->getParameter('crsf_inscription_inception');
$tokenValue = $request->get('token');
$token = new CsrfToken($tokenId, $tokenValue);
if (!$tokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
    throw new HttpException(400, 'Invalid token');
}
```